# How to handle front-end and back-end paths on browser refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm using React, React-router and Play Framework to serve and render an application.

This is what my Routes.jsx looks like:

```
const Routes = (
  <Route path="/">
    <Route component={App}>
      <Route path="attributes/:itemId" component={AttributesContainer}/>
      <IndexRoute component={ItemsContainer}/>
    </Route>
  </Route>
);

export default Routes
```

As you can see, path ***/attributes/:itemId*** renders a component called ***AttributesContainer***.

This path is called from ***ItemsContainer*** in this function:

```
_onClickAttributes(itemId) {
  browserHistory.push({pathname: '/attributes/' + itemId});
}
```

Everything works just fine there. But if I refresh the browser while in ***/attributes/:itemId***, back-end returns

```
Action Not Found
For request 'GET /attributes/5'
```

instead of the front end component. I understand the browser is doing a get request and that's why I get this message.

So, what's the best technique to handle this?

Comment: I think in this case you have a backend issue, not a front end one. What language/framework/webserver are you using on your server?

Comment: You will have to fix that on your backend. Basically, your backend needs to be set up to ignore anything after the `/`. How to do that depends on your backend.

Comment: @Deadron I'm using Play Framework 2.

Comment: @Timo how about using #. do you think that's a good approach?